# Schwa+Heh Pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, hebrew

Considering the emphasis we place on proper pronunciation, particularly for the [purposes](http://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.24b?lang=en&p2=Tosafot_on_Megillah.24b.49&lang2=en) of [*b'rachos*](http://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.24b?lang=en&p2=Rashi_on_Megillah.24b.33&lang2=en), [declarations](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Reading_the_Shema.2.9?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en), and [prayer](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2012/01/on-hebrew-pronunciation-controversy-in.html), how should a *heh* with a *schwa* under it be pronounced in an intermediate position in a word to satisfy the requirements? E.g. פדהאל, or [נהדר](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

פדהצור is actually not such a good example, because it doesn't have a sheva under the ה; there's no question, then, that it would be silent (like the ה at the end of the words תורה, מצוה, etc.). Perhaps you're thinking of פדהאל (Num. 34:28).

As I understand it, there should be an audible puff of breath in these cases - i.e., "neh-dar" (not "ne-dar"), "p'-dah-el" (not "p'-da-el"), etc. The closest English analogue I can think of is the dismissive "aah" (as in "never mind").

Comment: I have the same mesorah from my father, from his father who taught dikduk in Yeshivah University. (He held a doctorate in Semitic Languages). The way my father taught me is that the first syllable in נהדר should end with an audible heh, i.e. neh-dar.