# How do you pronounce the name אֱלוֹהַּ?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, pronunciation

Is the word אֱלוֹהַּ pronounced as:

1. "Elo-ha" or
2. "Elo-ah"?

DonielF pointed out [a similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77325). It seems to me that that question was asking for the reasoning of how Patach Genuvah works. I think that my question is addressing a specific word Elo-ah and what its correct pronunciation is. It seems to me that this word can deserve its own question of how to properly pronounce it. While spreading this lesson a little bit in Lakewood, one man called me and told me that he did a little bit of research and heard that (I take zero responsibility for any validity of this story), Rav Moshe Feinstein told his Shaliach Tzibbur (R' Aidelman) to pronounce the word as Elo-ha. He finished off the phone call telling me to do further research on this topic. And I did.

Edit: You're all totally right that the subject of this pronunciation has already been addressed in other questions. Great job to the community's very active involvement in combing through every question.

Answer (score 3):

I've always been used to hearing people say in Hallel:
"Milifnei Adon chuli aretz, milifnei **Eloha** Yaakov" ([Psalms 114,7](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.114.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Text_Only&ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
(מלפני אדון חולי ארץ מלפני אלוה יעקב). (Of course this name of HaShem also appears in other parts of Prayer and Scriptures.)

But it turns out that in Dikduk in Lashon Hakodesh, there is a rule of Patach Genuvah, which makes it that the "ah" noise of the patach is pronounced before that letter is pronounced. Even though I have come across two naysayers that have argued with me, I spoke with Rabbis and confirmed that this rule applies to this word. I spoke with a Rabbi in Lakewood, and a Rabbi in Clifton, and with Rabbi Moshe Meiselman. (And in the linked file later on, I bring an excerpt from R' Shabsai Sofer who explicitly addresses the pronunciation and common misconception regarding this word.)

So the proper way to pronounce that word (the name of HaShem) is:

- According to Ashkenazim: **Elo-ah**
- According to Sepharadim: **Elo-wah**

When practicing or teaching this to others, please be careful to not say the actual name of HaShem (this is one of the unerasable names). You can say, "Elo, and then, ah". Or, you can say the whole Passuk,

If anyone is interested, I compiled some Mareh Mekomos (source sheets) that discuss this rule of dikduk. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aga2mxecyiy082f/Patach%20Genuvah%20Packet.pdf?dl=0) (If you print these papers, please treat them with holiness, and dispose of only by burial/genizah.)

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Important info to know ,since one who says it incorrectly isnt mentioniong HaShems name and in result missed a word and one may not be yotzeh hallel. See Rabbeinu Yeruchum - Shulchan Aruch 422:6

Comment: The final heh is also a הּ, so it should be voiced

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying "Eloah" aloud as a practice word. Just like how you'd say "Elohim Acherim" repeatedly without hesitation. (This answer is total overkill to the point of being harder to understand IMO btw.)

Comment: (And it's hard to take grammar advice from a packet that spells משגיח or להגיה without the dagesh in the ג.)